# Hide content types in administration for certain user

Tags: nodes, users

I created a user role who can only create and edit a certain content type, this works as it should.

When they log in however, they can click the content box in the admin bar to see all content. I want them to be able to click there and get all the content that they have the permission to create, but other content types should not appear.

I can't find any setting for this is the user role and permissions setting, but perhaps I'm mistaking? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Content Access](https://drupal.org/project/content_access) module

> This module allows you to manage permissions for content types by role
>   and author. It allows you to specifiy custom view, edit and delete
>   permissions for each content type. Optionally you can enable per
>   content access settings, so you can customize the access for each
>   content node.

Comment: the content access module is not stable which means it is not an idea solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a custom [view](https://drupal.org/project/views) and filter it to the desired content. This also allows you to completely customize which options they have available to them.

Comment: It can be very good if you need a very customized output, but I guess it doesn't really worth the time, best is just to go with Content Access module.